# C# Programming in visual studio - how to open a local file in a web browser

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have a webpage that is on my computer that I want to open it in a web browser in a visual c# windows form program in visual studio here is what I have tried

```
private void openWebPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int size = -1;

    openFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C://";
    openFileDialog2.Filter = "HTML files (*.html)|*.html|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog2.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = true;
    openFileDialog2.Multiselect = false;
    openFileDialog2.Title = "Open HTML File";

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.

    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        string file = openFileDialog2.FileName;

        try
        {
            string htmlfile = File.ReadAllText(file);
            size = htmlfile.Length;

            filelocation = openFileDialog2.FileName;

            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();

            string a = openFileDialog2.FileName;

            this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("file:///" + a, System.UriKind.Absolute);  
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
```

right now it give an error that says

> Script error   an error has occurred in the script on this page.    line:383  Char: 3   error: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'  code:0  url:  File:///c:/Users/[username]%20[username]/Desktop/Webpage/Processing%20Js%20Webpage/Processing.js     Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

I'm stuck and cant think of what to do and some help would be nice thanks.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control uses an older version of IE, which your JS code does not support.

Comment: Have you tried using Selenium instead! Open your document in your favourite browser